# RowStyle in DataGrid working only partially

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, triggers, styles

This is weird, so I'm sure I'm missing something (almost) obvious here. I wish to control the appearance of the selected row and cell so I'm playing with the triggers. The triggering seems to work, because I see the settings I've maid with regarding the colors and thickness.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aquamarine"></Setter>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>

<DataGrid.CellStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

However, the problems is that the rows' background is colored in the default blue on all the columns containing data and in my custom aquamarine on the empty space to the right of the last column, just like the image below depicts.

[image]

What gives? My google-fu haven't shown anything about persistent defaults needed to be removed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default blue coloring is part of the `DataGridCell`'s `Template`.

You can retemplate the DataGridCell and omit this functionality, or you can instead just add a setter in your existing DataGridCell style's `IsSelected` trigger and set the `Background` to `Transparent`.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```